# Ruby on Rails running as local app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4

this is probably strange question but I wanted to make rails app that would function as regular desktop app.

I'm making regular web app, but I will have admin function where I manage clients. I'm not very confident with security of my app and I will be only one who uses it so I thought maybe I can use this part of code only on my windows machine.

I figured it out because I don't have SSL certificate and I wouldn't want to put something on web if i will be only one who uses it.

I also know that Rails is webframework, but is is only framework i know how to work with.

Comment: Run it and point the browser at it?

Comment: This is how Rails development works. You create the app, run the server, and go to http://localhost:8080 (or whatever port your server is running on) to access your app

Comment: is there some security concerns for using app in developement for yourself for long periods? i guess developement is not made for it, but sound good to me.

Comment: The security concerns are the same that always apply to a personal computer.

Comment: would it be different if i would use it on Cloud9 IDE?

Comment: to encrypt the data stored in the database (sqlite, postgres, mysql) the gem 'attr_encrypted' will encrypt the field values stored in the DB, ensure that your 'secret keys' are stored as environment variables in the terminal running the application 'export XXX_key=XXXXXX', then secure the app directory, the gem brakeman will review your code for security flaws.